# I want to get the time of starting an application

Tags: android

The time is displayed in Logcat,
and I want to get it by codes because Logcat doesn't always display the time.
Any of the ways of solving it will be acceptable
Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yon can try something like this:

1. At the start of the code you want to measure, add

   > int start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   >   This gives you start point
2. At the end of the code to measure, add

   > int end = System.currentTimeMillis();

> int duration = end - start; // That is duration you need.

Now you may append duration to file, post it to some service or do what ever you want to do with it...

Comment: But the result is not correct by this way.My code is following:PackageManager packageManager =   StartAnAppActivity.this.getPackageManager();   
          Intent intent=new Intent();   
          intent =packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.browser");   
          long time = System.currentTimeMillis();  
          startActivity(intent);   
          Toast.makeText(StartAnAppActivity.this, "time is "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time), 1).show();

Comment: You can't measure it this way since this is asynchronous operation - you send intent, but it does not block function from which you launched it. Intent is executed in parallel to your code, so you can't measure startup time this way. If you are measuring your own activity launch time, you should add measuring code inside startup code of that activity.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want to say but I'm poor at English.Then what about an app of system? like browser or something.

Comment: In video from Google io 2010 you have explanation how you can use certain tools to profile applications. Take a look at the http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA . Related projects and tools are at http://code.google.com/p/zippy-android/

Answer (score 1):

You could just store the time when the application starts, using a [Date()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) function. If it's the first line, then it'll get the start time, and you can print it out or whatever else you want, no problems.

Just a quick example of how you can use the date function. Log.d("Start_Time",new Date().toString())

Comment: ThanQ for replying, but I can't get the time application done starting, I want to get it by codes because I need to do it for 500 times or more, so I can't look at the screen for such a long time.

Comment: I want to get 500 times of how much time starting apps will use, and get an average time. So it's a huge task, I try to make it by coding an application or service to record it automagically